# Syntax error on line 16

Tags: macos, shell, scripting

To me the syntax seems to be written correctly, but I get an error on line 16....any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh

#This is script is meant to be an add on to another one I'm using. Based on the return code output it will mail me the message.

read -p "What is the file name? " variable
rc = $?

ls -al $variable
if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
        mail -s "$variable script did not complete" email address -- -f email address \
        << EOF Your script has failed with error code $rc << EOF;
elif [[ $rc = 0 ]]; then
        mail -s "Your script completed" email address -- -f email address \
        << EOF Your script completed with error code $rc. << EOF;
fi
```

Pasting seems to have messed up the format a little. Here's the pastebin link:

http://pastebin.com/1ub1EupC

Comment: http://shellcheck.net fails to parse this but makes a valiant attempt at trying and explaining what it thought was close. That might be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

The [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) starting `<< EOF` needs its end `EOF` at the start of a line of its own.

```
    mail -s "$variable script did not complete" email address -- -f email address << EOF
Your script $variable has failed with error code $rc.
EOF
```

If you use tabs (strictly tabs) for indentation, you can use:

```
    mail -s "$variable script did not complete" email address -- -f email address <<-EOF
    Your script $variable has failed with error code $rc.
    EOF
```

(I'm blithely assuming the syntax of your `mail` command is OK, though I'm not convinced of that, even with GNU `getopt()` reordering options.  If the two words `email address` are `email1@us.example.com` and `email2@uk.example.com` or something similar, then it would be more nearly OK.  For myself, I still prefer options before arguments.)

I would also prefer to include the failing script name in the body of the email as well as in the subject line.

Comment: In another, less "complicated," script the email function works perfectly. Now I don't get the line error, but it doesn't do anything. The ls command works great. So I'm curious if the error code isn't getting read correctly so the script isn't continuing? I appreciate the help so far!

Comment: Presumably, you've fixed the syntax problems like the spaces in the assignment to `rc`?  What do you get when you run the script with `sh -x yourscript.sh` (with any relevant arguments)?  If this code is in a function, then you may need to turn on tracing in the function: `set -x;` at the top of the function.  The `elif` with test should be replaced by a simple `else`; if the return code does not satisfy `$rc != 0`, then it must satisfy `$rc = 0`.